# What is a function decorator in python

Tags: python, decorator

What is a function decorator? Is it something we use to declare a function? Or is it like a constructor.

Comment: Do you per chance mean "function decorator"?

Comment: Heh, I didn't even notice that. I'll leave my answer for now.

Comment: yea my bad, it should be decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function decorator is simply a function intended to take a function as an argument and return a new function to use in its place. Python provides decorator syntax to simply its use. That is,

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```

The syntax takes care of applying the decorator to the original function and rebinding the result to the original name.

Comment: I assume you would first need to define function `foo` in both snippets?

Comment: Is `foo` or `bar` the decorator here?

Comment: I am assuming `foo` is defined previously; I'm only demonstrating the syntax involved. `foo` is the decorator; `bar` is the decorated function.

Comment: So in subsequent code, you would typically use `foo` instead of using `bar`?

Comment: No, you use `bar`. The name `bar` simply refers to a (possibly different) function than the one defined by the `def` statement.